# step by step instructions for installing eclipse on Windows 7?

Tags: installation, eclipse

It's almost unbelievable to me that I can't find this (especially anywhere on the eclipse site), but how do install Eclipse?  I'm using Windows 7.

I have downloaded eclipse which was a big zip file.  After unzipping it, there is no install file, just apparently an exe to actually run eclipse (that was the first surprise).  Running that, it complains that there's no JRE (I thought it would have come with it).  So I went and downloaded a JDK.  It still couldn't find what it needed so I had to manually modify the Path environment variable to point to jre/bin.

Now it can't find jvm.dll.

I'm sure I could hack around and make this work, but everything I'm doing seems so wrong, and I want to do this the clean & correct way. I swear I installed Eclipse before and definitely didn't need to modify any environment variables.

Are there instructions somewhere that I'm just missing?

Comment: Have you installed the JDK using a Windows installer? I believe those setup the environment so you can start Eclipse w/o extra configuration.

Answer (score 7):

Check step 7 in the below url about using eclipse in Winodws environment
http://www.wikihow.com/Download,-Install,-and-Run-JDK-and-Eclipse

> Once you have downloaded the Eclipse archive you will need to
>   decompress the zip file, which will create the unzipped Eclipse
>   folder. You may want to extract the archive to the root of C:\ drive,
>   thus creating the folder “C:\eclipse”, or just moved the extracted
>   eclipse folder to the root of C:\ drive if you extracted it already.
>   Since Eclipse does not have any installer, there will be a file inside
>   the Eclipse folder named eclipse.exe. You can double click on the file
>   to run Eclipse.

I too havent come across any eclipse installer or setup file for windows. So looks this is the most common way to start use eclipse in windows.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have downloaded and installed java 64 bit and not java 32 bits.
In addition, change the name of the directory from C:\Program Files\Java\jreX (X is a number) to C:\Program Files\Java\jre